# Pycharm cannot run after changing the Windows account name (CreateProcess error=2)

Tags: windows, path, pycharm, account

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv9oa.jpg)

My Windows account name was in Korean, so I changed the name to English due to compatibility issues with other programs. Since then I've had problems running this program, but I'm not sure how to change the file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be enough to update interpreter path in `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter - Show All (near combobox) - <Interpreter> - Edit`